# Salvando Arquivos em UTF-8 no lado do Servidor

Tags: php, html, codificação-de-caracteres

me ajudem com este código aqui em PHP:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Atualização de dados</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="upload.css"/>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round|Raleway:900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type:"text/javascript" src="../jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
<div><p id="header"><b>ATUALIZAÇÃO DE CONTEÚDO</b></p></div>

<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
require("../dbconnect.inc.php");


$assunto = isset($_POST['ass']) ? $_POST['ass'] : FALSE;
$aula = isset($_POST['aul']) ? $_POST['aul'] : FALSE;
$qURL = isset($_POST['qURL']) ? $_POST['qURL'] : FALSE;
$vid_nome = $_FILES['vidUpdt']['name'];
$aud_nome = $_FILES['audUpdt']['name'];
$img_nome = $_FILES['imgUpdt']['name'];
$txt_nome = $_FILES['txtUpdt']['name'];


//Diretórios raíz de uma aula
$_UPAul['pasta']['video'] = 'video/' . $assunto . '/' . $aula;
$_UPAul['pasta']['audio'] = 'audio/' . $assunto . '/' . $aula;
$_UPAul['pasta']['texto'] = 'texto/' . $assunto . '/' . $aula;
$_UPAul['pasta']['imagem'] = 'imagem/' . $assunto . '/' . $aula;

//UPDATE DO VIDEO
if(empty($vid_nome)==FALSE){
  ExcluiDir($_UPAul['pasta']['video']);
    if(!(file_exists('video/' . $assunto))){
    mkdir('video/' . $assunto . '/' . $aula,0777,true);
}else{
    mkdir('video/' . $assunto . '/' . $aula,0777);
    }
    $_UP['pasta']['video'] = 'video/' . $assunto . '/' . $aula . '/';
    $vid_URL = $_UP['pasta']['video'] . $vid_nome;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['vidUpdt']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta']['video'] . $vid_nome)) {
  // Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo
  echo "<p align='center' style='color:#8F8F8F'>Upload do video efetuado com sucesso!</p>"; 
} else {
  // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
  echo "<p align='center' style='color:#8F8F8F'>Não foi possível enviar o arquivo de video, tente novamente.</p> <br>";
}

}
?>
```

O que está acontecendo:
O nome do arquivo enviado do cliente para o servidor é armazenado corretamente no banco de dados MySQL, mas na hora de criar o arquivo no diretório especificado, o arquivo fica com vários caracteres especiais exibidos da maneira errada, o que ocasiona em falhas na chamada do arquivo quando este é requisitado pelo lado do cliente.

Já botei todos os arquivos na codificação UTF-8. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Não use caracteres especiais em nomes de arquivo. É a melhor forma de corrigir seu problema.

Comment: Eu faço essa recomendação para o usuário no instante de inserir os arquivos. Mas gostaria de saber se tem como contornar o problema de um jeito simples sem ter que dar este tipo de preocupação para o usuário.

Comment: @user3450942 se ele faz upload pela própria aplicação, é o caso de sanitizar os nomes antes de salvar, trocando caracteres especiais e acentuados por um equivalente ASCII. Se futuramente ele for fazer download pela aplicação, você pode até salvar o nome original do DB, assim ele não perde nada. Dependendo do caso, basta converter o nome pra base64, que resolve. Só cuidado com o overhead no tamanho do nome. Aliás, se for salvar o nome original do arquivo num DB, pode usar o próprio ID do banco para o nome do arquivo. file0000001, file000002 etc.

Comment: Desde que os tamanhos dos nomes não passem de 75% da capacidade do _filesystem_, basta isso: `$convertido= strtr(base64_encode($original), '+/', '-_');` e `$original = base64_decode(strtr($convertido, '-_', '+/'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o caso, o melhor é modificar o código, evitando caracteres especias.

Pode-se usar uma função simples de substituição como esta que adaptei de algum lugar que não lembro mais

```
function sanitize_filename($filename) {
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $string = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string);
    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $string = preg_replace(array('~[^0-9a-z]~i', '~[ -]+~'), '_', $string);     
    return $string;
}
```

E colocar no seu código desta forma

```
$assunto = isset($_POST['ass']) ? sanitize_filename($_POST['ass']) : FALSE;
$aula = isset($_POST['aul']) ? sanitize_filename($_POST['aul']) : FALSE;
$qURL = isset($_POST['qURL']) ? sanitize_filename($_POST['qURL']) : FALSE;
$vid_nome = sanitize_filename($_FILES['vidUpdt']['name']);
$aud_nome = sanitize_filename($_FILES['audUpdt']['name']);
$img_nome = sanitize_filename($_FILES['imgUpdt']['name']);
$txt_nome = sanitize_filename($_FILES['txtUpdt']['name']);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Acabei pesquisando sobre esta função e vi que dá para brincar de mais maneiras interessantes com ela hehehe. Aos outros que sugeriram soluções, irei testar o que vocês indicaram em breve e já dou o feedback. =)